# Is my summary of transistor behaviour (on or off) in saturation mode correct?

Tags: transistors, nmos, pmos, jfet

In the following Table, I made a summary of my understanding of the configurations in which the various sorts of field-effect transistors are on or off, in saturation mode.

Is my summary of transistor behaviour (on or off) correct (in saturation mode) ?

Is my approach of Table *clumsy* ? (why ?)
(I have updated the table in order to make the fix)

[image]

Comment: Well .. you're missing the important "linear region" and the entire operation of transistors as amplifiers?

Comment: as pjc50 said, your table would benefit from splitting 'on' into 'slightly on' (linear region) and 'very on' (hard switched) regions. It's not just that you're missing the amplifying region, which is a pity, but that the amplifying region doesn't make for a good 'very on' low loss switch if you're only interested in switching.

Comment: apologizes : I wish to summarize only the saturation mode. In that *saturation mode* context : is my table fine or clumsy ?

Comment: Saturation mode for FETs is not the same as saturation mode for BJTs. Check your terminology. Don't feel bad about it, I'm a very experienced engineer, and had it wrong for all these years!

Comment: @Neil_UK : ok, but please note that I didn't put BJT in the table : I put only Field Effect transistors, since $V_{GS}$ does not exist for BJT.

Comment: OK, I'll put it another way - how do you define 'saturation mode' for a FET?

Comment: @Neil_UK : I would define it as the voltage of VDS for which the current no more increases.

Comment: The definition of saturation for a FET is the part of the IDS/VDS diagram where IDS is essentially constant and controlled by VGS, and VDS varies over a large range. I don't think your table captures that at all.

Comment: @Neil_UK : ok, thank you.

Comment: Would somebody know why, in books, we never see the kind of summary Table that I tried to do ?

Comment: `why, in books, we never see the kind of summary Table that I tried to do ? – ` Because it's not very useful. It's a useful exercise, doing one, and then finding out what extra needs to be included to make it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing your work for you I will tell you that you can't talk about "saturation mode" for a MOSFET unless you include \$V_{DS}\$ in the discussion.

If you really want to describe whether the transistor is **in saturation** then you can't just say "on" or "off". That's not how we describe transistor behavior.

For an N MOSFET you say that it is "off" if \$V_{GS} > 0\$ but "on" if \$V_{GS} > V_{th}\$. That is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. But the way. Not important, but I don't know why you say instructor : I'm not a student since at least 30 years. I am not doing an exercice for a school. I ask myself my own questions. I'm not the one who put your answer "down" (I don't know who did). About the VGS : I understand your point. I need to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

For enh. mode using proper polarity when Vgs Vgs(th), it is just the threshold at some low current like 200uA so it is neither “on or off” but at the threshold of conduction like 2V/200uA=10kohm. Thus RdsOn is stated in the datasheet at one or two Vgs levels for “on” usually Vgs>=2Vgs(th).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your comment. So you mean that in order for the transistor to be "on", one need "x times" the threshold for the voltage. ok.